# PyQt Window not displaying on screen

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am a beginner learning PyQt and the following code is not displaying any window on the screen, though I can see that the build is successful. I'm not able to recognize the mistake, could you help me please?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not using pyqt nor windows, but maybe PyQt4 is too old. You'd better try PyQt5... :)

Comment: This works with my python (3.5) under Ubuntu 16.04. I had PyQt4 installed in advanced. Have you installed PyQt?

Comment: I've tried your code and I have not had any problems. What error does it generate or just not displayed?

Comment: Also, what OS do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by: "I can see that the build is successful"?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `sys.exit(app.exec_())` at the end of `main()` function.

This worked for me (I use python3):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

frame = QtGui.QMainWindow()
frame.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 400)
frame.setWindowTitle('FrameTitle')

frame.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```